# Slideshow module for Joomla doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, joomla, slider, nivo-slider

I am using a Nivo Slider based image slideshow module for **Joomla CMS, version 1.5.** The module is jQuery based and we are using **jQuery 1.6.3** for this one.

The slider works perfectly fine on FireFox and IE, as can be seen on our website. **It used to work fine on Chrome, too (tested with version 14) - *but it doesn't anymore and I don't have a clue why.***

On Chrome, all the images load fine, however, only the first slide is displayed and I believe the jQuery script returns an error. The console returns the following error: "Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined", on file jquery.min.js, line 4.
**The result is a still image - the first slide.** Everything else is there, the CSS, the initializing jQuery script and all the HTML involved.

I checked it already with **Chrome versions 14 and 15.** In both versions the result are the same.

I also already tried **uninstalling and re-installing the module**, using the **default values**, changing images & text and so on but nothing seems to get it working again on Chrome. I checked it out on different computers to see if it might be a problem with **Chrome's cache**, like the original Nivo Slider bug with Chrome. I even tried loading **different versions of jQuery**, all the way back to 1.4, **but still no change**.

Please note I have applied some scripting and CSS to complement the slider, more specifically there's a script that turns the first slide into a Youtube embed player and some CSS for caption styling. The javascript & CSS additions work fine on Chrome, however, **even when removing all the alterations I added, the slider module still doesn't work!**

Let me stress again that **it did work on Chrome before**, more over - **it does work perfectly fine on Firefox and IE**. I have no idea what had caused the change.

P.S. obviously you can take a look on Firefox or IE and see that everything on that module works including the CSS and Javascript I added.

- [Our Website](http://www.goabroadtraining.com/)
- [Slideshow Module Website](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images-slideshow/18640)

Comment: ## Links as promised: [Our website here](http://www.openmindprojects.com/training) | [Slideshow module website here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images-slideshow/18640) | [jQuery file used here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I didn't realize that at the time the access to the website was blocked outside our subnet because it is under construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it happens because there is a conflict between jquery library and mootools library. You can go in `"media/system/js/mootools.js"` and rename `mootools.js` to `_mootools.js` for example and it works.
I know that there is a more elegant way to fix it, where you can enabled a `Jquery.noConflict()` in your code. But I didn't try it.
Good Luck

Comment: Might be. I was actually meaning to update here long ago but have forgotten, as I have moved to a new job since then and had virtually no free time :(

So here is the update, and it is quite similar to your solution: the main page was calling jQuery v1.2.2 I believe and the module was calling v1.4.6 - and there was the conflict.